# How do I convert point cloud data to DICOM?

Tags: slicing

How can I convert 3D point cloud data to DICOM format (specifying slice width) or an equally scrollable sharp 2D image format?  Which software (preferably opensource or free) can I use to do this?

I've searched on Google and can't find anything.

Chris

Comment: This is almost something that could be done in an afternoon from scratch... What is the 3D point cloud data format? What sort of a DICOM output do you want - be specific, there are several possibilities!

Answer (score 2):

This answer is actually based on combining answers from 2 other questions ([this](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/a/6963/150) and [that](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/q/1262/150)).

The process isn't a single step and would be to as follows:

1. The point cloud data needs to be converted to a 3d mesh.
2. Convert the mesh to STL.
3. Slice the STL into [SVG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics).

For step one, the type of point cloud data would decide the software to use (for example, if it is GIS point cloud data, or 3D scanner point cloud data). A good end result of step 1 would be a VRML file. As you've not specified the type of point cloud data, I cannot suggest a software for it.

Step 2 would be to convert the mesh to STL which is easily doable using  [Meshlab](http://www.meshlab.net/).

For step 3, [Slic3r](http://manual.slic3r.org/advanced/svg-output) itself will work just fine to generate the SVG output you're looking for.