# Is it possible to convert a Las /Laz file into an STL or OBJ file?

Tags: 3d-models, scanning, file-formats, python

I would like to know if there is any tool/library (preferably python based) that could be used in parsing a Laz file to extract info that is normally found in 3d object files such as vertices. Which could be used to create printable 3d mesh.
I already tried Laspy and I could get the  x,y,z data from it but it is not a vertices info but rather a scale info. So I would either need a tool to give that or an algorithm for getting vertices from the data  from laspy.

Comment: It is working @Durodola Opemipo ?

Answer (score 2):

Given that [LAS/LAZ](https://www.loc.gov/preservation/digital/formats/fdd/fdd000418.shtml) is LiDAR point cloud data, there is a GIS tool called [las2tin](https://www.cs.unc.edu/~isenburg/lastools/download/las2tin_README.txt) to convert these files to a triangle based mesh called Triangular irregular networks or TIN by the GIS community. Other GIS tools should be able to do the same, for example [ArcGIS](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/3d-analyst/las-dataset-to-tin.htm).

Once you have the mesh, Google should be able to help you find a way to convert the TIN to an STL. You will need to scale down the STL after creation, as the TIN will probably be at 100% scale.

One example workflow for converting LAS data into an STL is:

- Using ArcScene: open DEM > convert to TIN > export to VRML
- Using MeshLab: open VRML > export to STL
- Using Meshmixer: extrude base > scale to fit standard printing parameters > save as finished STL

More details for the process that I got from Google are available [here](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=sites&srcid=ZGVmYXVsdGRvbWFpbnxzZ2NjYXJ0fGd4OjY5ZDk1OTY3MjY4OTY4NWM)